# Get a link using branch_match_id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, branch.io

In my app i have this link: hxxp://get.livesoccer.io/IuKk/0CRq5vArLx that redirects to this:

hxxp://livesoccer.io/news.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.90min.com%2Fembed%2Fposts%2F4003374-chelsea-star-pedro-loving-life-at-stamford-bridge-after-this-summer-s-failed-move-to-barca%3Fpartner%3D353549%26show-author%3Dtrue%26show-date%3Dtrue%26show-reads-counter%3Dtrue%26show-title%3Dtrue%26utm_medium%3Dapi%26utm_source%3DLiveSoccer%2B-%2Blive%2Bscores&_branch_match_id=322721456099402785

What I want to do is with the branch_match_id (322721456099402785) rebuild the original link (http://get.livesoccer.io/IuKk/0CRq5vArLx). How can i do this using web SDK from branch.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: the `branch_match_id` is not designed for this purpose. You want to look at the `init()` function, which will return the original Branch link URL plus other useful parameters. [Read about it in our documentation here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking#initbranch_key-options-callback)

Comment: I tried the `Init()` approach but all I get from my `branch_match_id` is "{\"+clicked_branch_link\":false,\"+is_first_session\":true}". So there's no way to track back the original link if someone manually shares the "transformed" `branch_match_id` link as opposed to the original short link?

Comment: @Milox the `_branch_match_id` param is a byproduct of the matching process that occurs when a Branch link is clicked, and is specific to a given session and device. The value itself is not actually tied to any specific link, so if a given user hasn't actually _clicked_ a Branch link, then we have no way to know which data should have been set. As an alternative, perhaps you could append the necessary data to the final redirected URL as query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As per @Alex Bauer ‘s answer, there’s currently no built-in way to get the original branch link from the branch_march_id solely, so an alternative if you can’t load the deep link info on init() is appending the original link to the query parameters when the link is transformed in order to be able to restore/redirect to the original.